# How to add notification badge in no icon menu item in android

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

How to add notification badge in no icon menu item in android?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7K1s.png)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194243/notification-badge-on-action-item-android) should help you out

Comment: @Vucko there menu item uses image, but my menu uses texts.

Comment: You can omit the image completely. No need to use it. :)