# Android - change 3 dots menu icon programmatically

Tags: android, android-menu

I've an actionbar with the default 3 dots menu icon.
I need to set an indicator on top of the icon in some cases (for example if a specific message arrives) and remove it in other cases.

I tried searching the web for solution to change the icon in real time, but I can't find any way.

Your help will be very appreciated :-)

Comment: The answers here might be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194243/notification-badge-on-action-item-android

Comment: Have you heard of [Badges](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/supporting/badge). They generally designed to be used with bottom app bars. But the logic might be similar for using with top app bar.